# Xcode Test files and assistant editors

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Xcode's behavior around test files and the assistant editor has been increasingly annoying me and I'm wondering if there's any way to customize the behavior to be more sane.

In the non-manual assistant editor mode where you can choose counterparts, test classes, etc., is there any way to configure the ordering of any of the files in those menus? Typically I'll have one test file corresponding to each class file, and I want that test file to open whenever I open the corresponding class file.  But I also might use that class in a few other test files that interact with that type of object. This makes XCode consider all these other test files as relating to the class and it just opens the first one alphabetically when I open the class file. I would really love if I could choose a default test class to open when I open a particular code class, or at least if I could set XCode to remember which test class I had open the last time I was editing this code class.

Another infuriating bug is that any time I edit the code in the main editor, the file open in the assistant editor jumps to the top of the file and I have to scroll back down to find what I was looking at there.

Are there any preferences or plugins to customize either of these behaviors in XCode 6?  Or does anyone have a good alternative work flow for doing TDD where you don't have to spend so much effort fighting against xcode?